# Splunk panel showing graph for a specific time range

Tags: monitoring, splunk, splunk-query

I am working with splunk. I want to pull logs for an api call for a specific range of time 9.30pm to 12:00 am on daily basis. Also, the average time taken for the call duraing that specific duration.

```
index="index_a" sourcetype="pqr" source="prq_source" "Success in api response"
```

Can someone guide me how to handle this how we can fetch for that particular duration for atleast 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (so long as you have the [automatic](https://antipaucity.com/2020/08/18/how-to-timechart-possibly-better-than-timechart-in-splunk/#.YRZp4-0pBAd) field `date_hour` created by Splunk):

```
index="index_a" sourcetype="pqr" source="prq_source" "Success in api response" earliest=-7d
| where (date_hour>=21 AND date_minute>=30) OR date_hour>=22
| stats avg(call_duration) as avg_call by success_id
```

If `date_hour` & date_minute *aren't* being automatically supplied by Splunk, you can create them yourself with [`strftime`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/DateandTimeFunctions#strftime.28X.2CY.29):

```
| eval date_hour=strftime(_time,"%H"), date_minute=strftime(_time,"%M")
```